# suggestions on technology choice for a specific rich/thick client app

Tags: silverlight, apache-flex, excel, html, drag-and-drop

I have a django site where I'm thinking about making a rich/thick client app to allow the user to do operations that would otherwise be really difficult to otherwise.

some of the requirements would be things like

- importing xls, csv documents
- being able to manipulate data from the site and/or from the imported xls in a drag and drop fashion (e.g. put a bunch of users in groups, etc)
- etc

It seems the rich client choices out there seem to be

- silverlight
- flex
- HTML5 + whatever.

and thick client

- .NET
- Java

I'm not crazy about making a thick client because (desktop/laptop) platform independence would be nice.
HTML5 would allow me to offer stuff to users on tablets i suppose,... but it's a luxury and doesn't really fit the main use case anyway.

If there is a service provider out there that has a platform for doing things like this that i can just leverage, well that would be awesome too.

Any suggestions from personal experience here would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Caveats: I'm working in Flex 3, and have never used Silverlight, and I agree with your thick-client problems.

Sounds like HTML5 is your best choice. The table-layout mechanism in HTML is far superior to what's in Flex. So if you want to display spreadsheets, that's your best bet.

Flex/Silverlight are traditionally better for Audio/video/animations/vector graphics, but that's becoming less and less the case. Sounds like you don't need those anyway.

HTML/JavaScript supports file upload, drag&drop, etc... Libraries like [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) can help make your program look like an application.

Your best option is to find applications that do what you want to do (e.g., Google Docs -- spreadsheet) and find out how they implemented it. Be inspired.